# Can I convert an Iterator of Result to Result of Iterator?

Tags: rust, iterator

Until now, I have used [`std::fs::read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_to_string.html) and then [`String.lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.lines)'s [`std::str::Lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Lines.html) (which is an `Iterator<Item = &str>`) to read a file "line by line". This obviously reads the whole file into memory, which is not ideal.

So, there's [`BufRead.lines()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) to read a file truly line by line. This returns [`std::io::Lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Lines.html) (which is an `Iterator<Item = Result<String>>`).

How do I convert from one iterator type to the other without `collect`ing first?

Comment: How would you know if the iterator will yield an error if you haven't yet iterated over it?

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the iterator? How do you want to exhaust it?

Comment: @kmdreko Yeah, kind of a dumb question in retrospect. 

Comment: @user4815162342 To reduce the boilerplate for each solution of Advent of Code's daily challenges, I've received an `Iterator<&str>` as a parameter. This worked because I always passed `String.lines()`. Now I wanted to pass `BufRead.lines()`, which of course is not directly possible. So I basically have to change all my signatures to take `Iterator<Result<String>>`? How can I have both without duplicating much of the code?

Comment: For what it's worth, reading the whole input into memory won't be an issue for AoC unless you're on severely limited hardware.

Comment: @cafce25 Yeah, I know. Just a personal challenge to be memory and computationally efficient. `Result::unwrap` seems to be a pragmatic approach here, for these one-off programs where reading the file is essential anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transform a `Iterator<Item = Result<_, _>>` into `Result<Iterator<Item = _>, _>` because if we haven't iterated the iterator yet we don't know whether we yield an error.

What you can do is to `collect()` all items ahead of time into a `Result<Vec<_>, _>` (which of course you can iterate over) since [`Result` implements `FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.65.0/src/core/result.rs.html#2024).

If you're fine with getting `Err` only for the first `Err` (and successfully iterating over all items until that), you can also use [`itertools::process_results()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/fn.process_results.html):

```rust
let result: Result<SomeType, _> = itertools::process_results(iter, |iter| -> SomeType {
    // Here we have `iter` of type `Iterator<Item = _>`. Process it and return some result.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to avoid a collection, since that would mean running through the whole iterator once just to unpack all of the `Result`s.

I suspect that the problem you really want to solve is how to map/filter an iterator of `Result<String, _>` without calling `unwrap` on every line. The approach here is not to turn `Iter<Result<T, E>>` into `Result<Iter<T>, E>`, but rather unpacking the `Result` type inside each map/filter, then repackaging the output in a Result to push any errors through to the next step.

Here's a generic example:

```rust
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{BufReader, BufRead},
}

fn parse_line(input: String) -> usize {
    // .. Dummy code that works on an input line
    todo!()
}

fn parse_lines() {
    let lines: Lines<BufReader<File>> = BufReader::new(
        File::open("my_file.txt").unwrap()
    ).lines();

    // HERE! Iterate over Result<T>
    let new_iter = lines.map(|line: Result<String, Error>| {
        // We can't pass a `Result` into our `parse_line` function,
        // so we unpack it first.
        match line {
            // If no error, do work with the contents of the `Ok` val.
            Ok(s) => Ok(parse_line(s)),
            // We don't want to do any destructive error handling 
            // prematurely, so we pass any errors back up the chain.
            Err(e) => Err(e)
        }
    };
}
```

Note that in almost every instance, you'll still want to do some sort of error handling at the end of the map/filter chain. This is typically done by `collect`ing the iterator into a `Result` type, e.g. `Result<Vec<_>>`, like mentioned by Chayim. But the approach I demonstrated avoids calling `collect` multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

You can't there has to be an owner of the values which is the full `String` in case of `String.lines`.
You can however turn the `Iterator<Item = Result<String>` into an iterator over `Strings`:

```rust
let mut read = BufReader::new(File::open("src/main.rs").unwrap());
let lines_iter = read.lines().map(Result::unwrap_or_default);
```

You can take an `Iterator` over items of either `String` or `&str` like this:

```rust
fn solve<T: AsRef<str>>(input: impl Iterator<Item = T>) {
    for line in input {
        let line = line.as_ref();
        // do something with line
    }
}
```